# How to get tag from text with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the tag and class name from the text.

Example HTML:

```
<a _sp="p2481888.m1379.l3250" href="https://www.ebay.com/b/Electronics/bn_7000259124">Electronics</a>
```

How can I get the tag and class name? `a` and `p2481888.m1379.l3250`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Source = input("Enter the source: ")
Request = requests.get(Source, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.59"})
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Request.text, "html.parser")

Target = Soup.find_all(text="Electronics")

print(Target)
```

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: The beautiful soup quick start documentation has a relevant example, looping over all links in a document: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `find_all(text="Electronics")`, it returns the *text*, in your case `Electronics`. To get the `a`, you can use [`.previous_element`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element), and then, to get the tag's name, use [`.name`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name). The text `p2481888.m1379.l3250` is whin the tag's [attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes), access it using `[]`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<a _sp="p2481888.m1379.l3250" href="https://www.ebay.com/b/Electronics/bn_7000259124">Electronics</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

target = soup.find_all(text="Electronics")

for tag in target:
    a_tag = tag.previous_element
    print("Tag name:", a_tag.name)
    print(a_tag["_sp"])
```

Output:

```
Tag name: a
p2481888.m1379.l3250
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass the tag’s name directly to `find_all()`:

```
target = soup.find_all("a", text="Electronics")

for tag in target:
    print("Tag name:", tag.name)
    print(tag["_sp"])
```

Comment: @Mestedepsu I’ve edited my answer with further detail

Comment: Can I do it without loop? I just need one row. It returns two rows.